# Arduino Nano IOT33 - Using flash

Tags: flash, arduino-nano-33-iot

I'm looking for a way to store data on flash as on ESP8266 or ESP32 using `FS.h`,  `LITTLEFS.h` but it fails.

Is is possible on Nano IOT33 ?

Comment: the SAMD21 on Nano IoT has only 256 kB of flash. esp has at least twice as much. and file system is usually used on esp with 4 MB flash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this library can be used:

https://github.com/cmaglie/FlashStorage

Library: FlashStorage library for Arduino

About info: A convenient way to store data into Flash memory on the ATSAMD21 and ATSAMD51 processor family

Mentioned in external related article (thanks to Juraj): https://forum.arduino.cc/t/persistent-storage-for-arduino-nano-33-iot-no-eeprom/623137

**UPDATE**

(See remark of Juraj below: this is NOT for a Nano IOT33)

See Library: https://github.com/khoih-prog/FS_Nano33BLE

About info: Wrapper of FS (LittleFS or not-advisable FATFS) for Arduino MBED nRF52840-based boards, such as Nano_33_BLE boards. This library facilitates your usage of FS (LittleFS or FATFS) for the onboard flash. FS supports power fail safety and high performance

Mentioned in:
https://forum.arduino.cc/t/fs-nano33ble-library-for-nano-33-ble-using-littlefs-fatfs/900463

Comment: That one I saw, but it seemed as EEPROM more than FS

Comment: It's not the same thing, but you can kind of mimic it (it both stores data).  As Juraj already mentioned, it also is about the amount of memory.

Comment: I updated my answer with a FS library.

Comment: Nano BLE is a different board with a different MCU and a an Arduino core based on mbed. the nRF52840 has 1 MB flash memory

Comment: @Juraj Thanks for that remark, I will keep the answer but make a comment just to keep others informed.